# BeautifulSoup ignore nested tables inside table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Working with BeautifulSoup for Python to parse a web page (that unfortunately is written mostly in tables).

Here's an excerpt of what I'm trying to work with

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="4">
    <div class="shortmenucats">
        <span style="color: ">
            -- Fresh Baked Pastries --

        </span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>  
  <td width="80%" valign="top">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="shortmenurecipes">
                        <span style="color: #000000"> Chocolate Doughnut Holes </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td width="5%" valign="top"></td>
  <td width="10%" valign="top" align="right" colspan="1">
    <div class="shortmenuprices">
        <span style="color: #000000"></span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td width="5%" valign="top" colspan="1">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Those are two rows from a table with 10 rows in it and they alternate like that (div in td, table in td, div in td, table in td, etc).

I'm using BeautifulSoup to call a find_all on the parent table and it's returning duplicates of every other row because of the nested  tags in the nested table.

I started by doing a `table.find_all('td', recursive=False)` but that didn't return any of the s at all. 
If I call a `findChildren()` on the parent table, I get a list with one result but it has all of the children inside of the result.

Am I doing something wrong? I don't know how to figure this out.

If you want the actual website I'm parsing from it's here:
http://138.23.12.141/foodpro/shortmenu.asp?sName=University+of+California%2C+Riverside+Dining+Services&locationNum=02&locationName=Lothian+Residential+Restaurant&naFlag=1

It's pretty messily coded. I'm just trying to parse it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even if it's just a way to remove the duplicates.

Thank you.

Comment: So what parts exactly are you trying to extract?  The text in the `span`s?  Or, what else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can identify your target tables by their depth in the HTML.

Here is some code which will select those tables nested at depth 3:

```
tables = soup.findAll("table")
depth3 = []
for t in tables:
  if len(t.find_parents("table")) == 3:
    depth3.append(t)
```

For your page this results in 6 tables selected - three for the headers ("Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner") and three for the menus. They alternate - header, menu, header, menu, etc, so you could just process the tables at positions 1, 3 and 5.

Your parsing should a lot easier now.

Answer (score 1):

Another option here would be to rely on the class names of the menu and categories inside and use `recursive=False` only when going down to the direct parent of an element.

**Complete working code** extracting the menu:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://138.23.12.141/foodpro/shortmenu.asp?sName=University+of+California%2C+Riverside+Dining+Services&locationNum=02&locationName=Lothian+Residential+Restaurant&naFlag=1"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))

container = soup.find('div', class_='shortmenutitle').find_next_sibling('table').tr
for td in container.find_all('td', recursive=False):
    title = td.find('div', class_='shortmenumeals')

    print title.text.strip()
    for item in td.table.find_all('tr', recursive=False)[1].table.find_all('tr', recursive=False):
        print item.text.strip()
    print "-----"
    print
```

Prints the complete menu (no duplicates):

```
Breakfast
-- Fresh Baked Pastries --
Chocolate Doughnut Holes
Double Chocolate Mini Muffin
Fresh Baked Blueberry Bagel
Fresh Baked Plain Bagel
-- Breakfast Parfait Bar --
(V,GF) Breakfast Parfait Bar
-- Hot Cereal & Toppings --
(V) Cream of Wheat
-- Breakfast Offerings --
(V) Belgium Waffle Bar with Condiments
(V) Eggs Rancheros
(V) Vanilla Scented French Toast
(V)Hash Browns
(V.GF) Scrambled Eggs
Corned Beef Hash
Turkey Sausage Patty
-- Omelet Bar --
(V,GF) Omelet Bar (Egg Whites Available Upon Request)
-----

Lunch
-- Soup & Deli Bar --
(V) Broccoli Cheese
Artisian Bread Bar
Chicken Tortilla
N Y Style Deli Bar
-- Global Sizzle --
(V) Jasmine Rice
(V) Steamed Sugar Snap Peas
(V) Thai Vegetable Spring Roll
Red Thai Curry Chicken (contains peanuts)
Sweet Thai Chili & Plum Dipping Sauces
Thai Curry Shrimp w/ Green Pepper
-- Urban Kitchen --
(V) Peruvian Beans
Peruvian Rotissere Chicken
-- The Grill --
(GF) Marinated Grilled Chicken Breast
(V) Skinny Fries
Turkey Club Melt
-- Healthy Vegetarian Bar --
(V) Southwestern Corn Salad
Southwest Soy Beef Wrap
-- Desserts --
Bakery Parfait Bar
Chocolate 1/2 Sheet Cake
Chocolate Mousse
Sugar Free Strawberry Orange Jell-O Gems
-- Continous Service 2pm-4:30pm --
(V) Vietnamese Tofu Spring Roll w/Sauces
Rotini w/Chicken Tomato Cream Spinach
Rotini w/Tomato Cream Spinach
Vietnamese Spring Roll with Tofu
-----

Dinner
-- Soup & Deli Bar --
(V) Broccoli Cheese
Artisian Bread Bar
Chicken Tortilla
N Y Style Deli Bar
-- Spinellis Pizza --
(V)French Bread Three Cheese Pizza
French Bread Pepperoni Pizza
-- Global Sizzle --
Beef Pho Bo Bar
Vegetable Pho Chay Bar
-- Urban Kitchen --
Mashed Sweet Potatoes
Rotissere Porkloin w/Apricot Demi Glace
-- The Grill --
(GF) Marinated Grilled Chicken Breast
(V) Seasoned Wedge Fries
Chicken Tenders
-- Healthy Vegetarian Bar --
(V) Cut Corn
(V) Steamed Broccoli
(Vgn) Black Bean Tostadas
-- Desserts --
Bakery Parfait Bar
Chocolate 1/2 Sheet Cake
Chocolate Mousse
M & M Rice Krispy Treats
Oreo Cheesecake
Peach Maple Cobbler
Sugar Free Strawberry Orange Jell-O Gems
-----
```

Comment: Oh. Awesome! Shorter and more readable than my code. 

This was my first time using BeautifulSoup so I really appreciate the help!